# how to position Tooltip over the cursor in Material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tooltip

I use react": "18.2.0", @mui/material": "5.9.3"
I need to display the Tooltip at the cursor location.
Props "followCursor" is not suitable because I have interactive content (inside there is a slider with image)
How to position Tooltip over the cursor in any place of its location or set coordinates in material/Tooltip ?

Comment: There was a feature request where one could vote on https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/24377#issuecomment-758569817 Maybe still vote there and someday they'll reconsider. Also seems to have instructions/examples on how to implement it yourself :-/